# SQL Server 2008 reducing length of string automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to read data by parsing XML in my SQL Server stored procedure. I have a base64 image as an XML attribute. I have been trying to read the length of the column and inserted string in the column.

- Table name: `sampleone`
- Columns: id, imagedata (`varchar(max)`)

XML format:

```
<testdoc> 
    <filescollection> 
        <file_data> --base64encodedImage  </file_data> 
    </filescollection>  
</testdoc>
```

We are checking xml data with the following select command

```
SELECT      
    Pers.value('(file_data)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'imagetest'   
FROM  
    @p_files_xml.nodes('/testdoc/filescollection[1]') as EMP(Pers)
```

Which shows: 13000

But when we `INSERT` it in table and try to find the length we get 1200

```
SET @image = (SELECT  
                  Pers.value('(file_data)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)')
              FROM  
                  @p_files_xml.nodes('/testdoc/filescollection[1]') as EMP(Pers) ) 

INSERT INTO sampleone VALUES ('1', @image)

SELECT LEN(imagedata)  
FROM sampleone
WHERE id = '1'
```

Result is 1200

What is the reason behind this truncation? I know that the size more than 8000 is truncated but I even tried with `nvarchar` so `varchar(max)` + `nvarchar(n)` would not lead to the same.

Comment: Can you check what `SELECT LEN(@image)` returns before you insert? I would think you're selecting only **parts** of your original XML to insert - therefore it's a lot smaller than the whole XML

Comment: What is the definition of your table `sampleone` and how is `@image` declared?

Comment: @marc_s I think you are right on this one.I made a webservice to call stored procedure that would do 
SELECT imagedata FROM sampleone 
and I got the desired output.In short yes, I was only selecting part of xml.